# How to return an empty response with grape?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, rack, ruby-grape

I have a `format :xml` Grape::API and for a delete request I want to return an empty response.

Everything I try to enter though, true, false, nil, it tries to convert to xml. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
delete do
  # your code...
  body false
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you don't. Since blank body is not a valid xml. But if you insist:

```
module NullXml
  def self.to_xml
    ""
  end
end

# grape endpoint
delete "/something" do
  # do the deletion
  NullXml
end
```

Comment: What is the proper response that it should return? I'm using DataMapper which overrides the `to_xml` method in weird ways. I want to make sure I'm returning the proper response if no records are found.

Comment: You should return a status 200 with a valid xml. The xml content can be <staus>OK</status> or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

For me this did the trick

```
    rack_response('', 404)
```